# Shift Pattern and Populating the names automatically in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 tables in excel and am trying to update the list of names on a daily basis in one of the tables.

Table 1 consists of a shift pattern per Agent Name as can be seen below.

[image]

In another table I have the shifts included where it will be updated on a daily basis based on the shift the agent is working and the date.

Table 2:

[image]

Can someone help me to updated automatically the name of the agent rather than inputting the agent name manually?

Expected Output:

[image]

Based on the 18/12/2020 (today) and the shift assigned to the agent, the agents names is populated.

Can someone help?

Comment: add another column besides the "Agent x" column" n use index match to 'load' the names'. ref : https://exceljet.net/index-and-match | give a try n share us how far u get/finish.. ( :

Comment: @p._phidot_ - Take you for your response it helped me get the shift number and shift agent name using Index + match,Now I am trying to get the name depending on the shift patter but i cannot use vlookup because it will just take the first agent name :/

Comment: then try to 'number' she shift pattern such as "9am-5pm1","9am-5pm2","9am-5pm3" and so on.

Comment: @p._phidot_ - I have tried doing that but it is still not working because everyday the pattern shift changes so somehow i have to populate the name next to shift pattern

Comment: it sounds like to me you need 2 lookups, one inside the other. Whatever you decide to do or use (vlookup or index-match), for automation on this you will need 2 lookups, one inside the other. one probably looking up a master table of agents-name on the day & their shift patterns. and the outer lookup looking up that against time.